# How many variables can be included in one multiple regression model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, variable

I was wondering if there is any limitation regarding the number of independent variables if I want to simultaneously include all variables in one regression model.

Answer (score 0):

Not in principle, but there will be practical limits based on computing power, sample size and multiple testing issues.

Comment: What happens when the number of independent variables exceeds the number of observations?

Comment: Then you have a choice between infinitely many model instances that all fit the data perfectly. I suppose you could call that a principled limitation.

Comment: Be a little cautious: having more variables than observations does not imply the regression will fit perfectly!

Comment: Yes, not in general, I was thinking of linear regression only.

Comment: This has been discussed here: [modelling with more variables than data points](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223486/modelling-with-more-variables-than-data-points)

Comment: How can we calculate number of observations in linear regression using SPSS?

Comment: If your data are properly formatted, the number of observations should be equal to the number of rows in your SPSS table, so you can just look at the number of the last line.

Comment: Could you please talk more specifically? which line and rows are you referring to?

Comment: *Especially* in linear regression, having more variables than observations is no guarantee of a perfect fit.  As an example, suppose all the variables are multiples of each other.  The point is that the proper measure of how many variables there are is not their count: it's the dimension of the vector space they span.